# fine-uploader : how to reference html file in templates folder

Tags: templates, fine-uploader

This might be a stupid question, but going over the documentation left me still puzzling about the html files in the templates folder.  Since the html files in the templates folder contain solely a script tag containing the template's markup, I was thinking I'd reference the html file in my page so that I could keep the template's markup from further cluttering up my page.

Can I simply change the template file's extension to ".js" & use a script tag in my page to reference the "re-extensioned" template file?

Thanks,

Orion